# how to show row no in LongListSelector in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8

i want to show row no's in the textblock such as 1 ,2 ,3..... and so on depending upon the item index value

```
as like 
1.    value  value
2.
3.


 <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" Margin="0,0,-12,0"
 ItemsSource="{Binding TaskList}" SelectionChanged="MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged"
 Foreground="Black" Height="654" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
         ....
 <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Text="{ 1}" />
```

how can i do it

```
  <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding TaskList}" SelectionChanged="MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged" Foreground="Black" Height="654" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Style="{StaticResource bordercss}" >
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Grid.Background>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Text="{Binding }" />
                            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding title}" Style="{StaticResource textbold}" />
                            <Image  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  Source="/Assets/priority_low.png" Margin="5" Height="25" />

                            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left"   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Source="/Assets/client_icon.png" Margin="5,5,0,5" Width="23"/>
                            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding clientname}" Style="{StaticResource textsimple}"  />

                            <Image  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  Source="/Assets/contact_icon.png" Margin="5,5,0,5" Width="17"/>
                            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding customercontact}" Style="{StaticResource textsimple}"   />

                            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"  Source="/Assets/address_icon.png" Margin="5,5,0,5" Width="20"/>
                            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding address}" Style="{StaticResource textsimple}"   />

                            <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="left" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding expdate}" Margin="-12,0,-12,-12" Background="#FFD6D6D6" Foreground="Black" Height="80"  />

                            <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Content="Status" Margin="-10,0,-12,-12" Background="#FFD6D6D6" Foreground="Black" Padding="0,0,5,0" Height="80"  />

                        </Grid>

                    </Border>

                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Comment: yup Aman id no is there

Comment: just bind that id to the textblock in the datatemplate. That's what I did in my listbox, I think the same would work for a LLS as well.

Comment: id no is different it like 201, 1002 any thing but i want 1,2,3

Comment: ok, its easy, please share the TaskList class type in the question.

Comment: Please find the code  and i want change the image if value is 1 then Assets/priority_low.png and so on

Comment: added rest in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best solution But could help you in some ways.

In your TaskList type class definition

just add a member like

```
public class YourClass
{
public int BindingId{get;set;}
}
```

Now at the place where the TaskList is getting filled

make a loop like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < TaskList.Count; i++)
{
TaskList[i].BindingId= i;
}
```

after the completion of the loop you will get an auto increment number attached with every item of the list. Just use that for the binding.